# Unable to add Gradle Dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-dependencies

I am trying to add this dependency to gradle, but I am receiving the below errors about other dependencies which I have not added in the first Place.

Errors :

[image]

Dependency I am trying to add is `com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.3`

build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pf.datetimepicker"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.3'
}
```

Comment: Never ever use `:+` as a version number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which I have not added in the first Place.

Sure you did...

Look at the source of the library you got. https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/blob/master/library/build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
```

First, you need `compileSdkVersion 25` for those to even work, then you need to allow Android Studio to "Install Repository and Sync Project" or do it yourself by updating the SDK Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion` and`targetSdkVersion`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pf.datetimepicker"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.3'
}
```

Comment: Small correction : buildToolsVersion has to be '25.2.0'

Comment: Actually it should be "25.0.2" because "25.2.0" is not available yet, but with double quotes is ok

Answer (score 1):

Change your compile and targetsdk to 25

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed the newest version of android support libraries. Just open SDK manager and install them. [See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvJrQ.png)